# COUNTIF not accepting "[x]" anymore

Tags: string, openoffice-calc

It might have been some update I did but since about two months ago, my OpenOffice (4.1.1) does not read **"[x]"** correctly anymore.

I've used it as a substitute of a tickbox in a database but suddenly it started giving me:

```
=COUNTIF(G2:G589;"[x]")   = 0
```

even though I know for a fact that there's more than 400 entries with that exact string.

Did they change how brackets work somehow?

There's no way the function just has an overflow, right? Because that would be ridiculous.

---

This works just fine though:

```
=COUNTIF(G2:G589;"-")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_COUNTIF_function.

"It can be very important to check the settings on the Tools menu – Options - OpenOffice.org Calc - Calculate dialog: ... If the checkbox is ticked for Enable regular expressions in formulas, the condition will match using regular expressions".

See: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Calc

Is the checkbox ticked? Then `=COUNTIF(G2:G589;"\[x]")`.

Within regular expressions the `[` has special meaning. So see: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer#Special_characters

Comment: Oh, right.. I ticked that checkbox a while ago. That might've been the time it stopped working. Thanks!